# Delete XML node with AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xmlnode

I'd like to delete some XML node with AS3. I've searched on google how to do that, but nothing seems to work.

Here a part of my XML :

```
<feed xmlns:xxxx="xxxx" xmlns:opensearch="xxx" xmlns="xxxx">
    <title/>
    <updated>date</updated>
    <author>
        <name>xxxxx</name>
    </author>
    <id>urn:tag:api@xxxx,date</id>
</feed>
```

Here my AS3 :

```
package {

  import flash.text.TextField;
  import flash.events.*;
  import flash.utils.*;
  import flash.display.*;
  import flash.net.*;

    public class Hello extends Sprite
    {  

    // Attributs
    private var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    // Constructor
    public function Hello()
    {
      // Call XML Method
      XMLcall();
    }

    // XMLcall Method
    private function XMLcall():void
    {
      xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("xxx"));
      // When loaded, add event and launch XMLparser
      xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, XMLcreate);
    }

    // XMLCreate Method
    private function XMLcreate(e:Event):void
    {
      // Create var myXML which contains the xml
      var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

      // Delete node
      delete myXML.author;

      // Save as myxml.xml
      var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
      var fileRef:FileReference=new FileReference();
      fileRef.save(myXML, "myxml.xml");
    }

    }
}
```

This code works but the node "Author" is still in my xml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to consider the name space, replace this line:

```
delete myXML.author;
```

with:

```
var ns:Namespace = myXML.namespace();
delete myXML.ns::author;
```

and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try add namespace when delete the node, And [this page](http://coursesweb.net/actionscript/xml-e4x-namespaces) may help

```
var ns:Namespace = myXML.namespace("xxxx");
delete myXML.ns::author;
```